# Rails - controller to separate view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, routes

In rails, I can say

```
match 'user/:id/article/:id' => 'article#show'
```

Here the article#show, would use the Article controller, in the show action. And it would present the show view in the article folder. But what if I wanted to be specific and say show action in article controller, and present the xxx view in the xxx folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify what page is rendered in the controller.
Example:

```
 render 'products/show'
```

That will render `app/views/products/show.html.erb`.